# How to tell if "which" refers to subject or object of main clause?

Tags: pronouns, subordinate-clauses

I have not been able to find a satisfactory answer regarding rules about this issue. What I have heard are lots of opinions:

> Here is a picture of my house, which I like very much.
>
> Here is a picture of my house that I like very much.

In the second example, **that** clearly refers to the subject of the main clause, since we could omit it and it would still mean the same thing:

> Here is a picture of my house I like very much.

In the first example, is there any rule about what **which** refers to? There is some ambiguity otherwise.

Comment: All three sentences contain (perhaps different extents of) ambiguity. Such is the English language.

Comment: No, the "which" example is ambiguous.

Comment: There is no object in the main clause here. Scratches head. Shrugs ...

Comment: @Araucaria "my house" is object to the preposition "of"

Comment: @as4s4hetic In the second example, with "that" introducing a defining clause and "my house" being a well-defined noun phrase, it is quite clear that the relative clause refers to the undefined noun phrase "a picture".

Comment: @Jason210 The only solution to disambiguate an ambiguous sentence is to express it otherwise, for example: *I like this picture of my house very much.*

Comment: @Gustavson  Ok, there's no 'object of the main clause'

Comment: @Gustavson ref the second example, to my ear it's the use of 'my' that diminishes, without removing altogether, the ambiguity, by making the other interpretation somewhat clunky. Compare 'Here is a picture of a house that I like very much" - I find that just as ambiguous as the first OP example.

Comment: The omissibilty of "that" has nothing to do with the subject of the main clause, but that of the relative clause, i.e. it cannot be dropped if the relativised element is subject of the latter. In your examples, the relativised element is object in the relative clause and is thus omissible in your 2nd example. There is ambiguity in both examples. In the 1st we cannot tell if the relativised element is anaphoric to "a picture of my house" or just "my house". And in your 2nd example it is not possible to tell if the relativised element is anaphoric to "picture of my house" or just "house".

Comment: @BillJ Prezackerly so.

Comment: Since the main clause has only a subject and no object, are you trying to ask whether there is some way of figuring out whether a relativiser refers to an _entire_ noun phrase, or just to a specific sub-constituent within a noun phrase? If so, then no. There is no way to do that. It will always refer back to the _last_ anaphorisable constituent (so “my brother's girlfriend who is 23” cannot mean that the brother is 23), but how much of the noun phrase that constituent makes up is entirely context-dependent. If that's not what you're trying to ask, then I don't understand the question.

Comment: Because I am new here I cannot vote up comments, but I found BillJ's answer to be the most helpful in analysing my examples.

Comment: *I like my house very much.* Like it was an ice cream cone. But otherwise, it's all ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's ambiguity when you try to analyze a sentence devoid of any communicative context. But since language is "quite often"  used for communication, other things serve to help disambiguate; such as perceived speaker's intention, the topic of the discourse, the intended function of the sentence.   If they don't, you can always ask your interlocutor  whether he is  referring  to the picture or to the house.